# How to express a hex literal in Spark SQL?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL.  I have searched the [language manual for Hive/SparkSQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) and googled for the answer, but could not find an obvious answer.

In MySQL we can express a hex literal `0xffff` like this:

```
mysql>select 0+0xffff;
+----------+
| 0+0xffff |
+----------+
|    65535 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But in Spark SQL (I am using the beeline client), I could only do the following where the numerical values are expressed in decimal not hexidecimal.

```
> select 0+65535;
+--------------+--+
| (0 + 65535)  |
+--------------+--+
| 65535        |
+--------------+--+
1 row selected (0.047 seconds)
```

If I did the following instead, I would get an error:

```
> select 0+0xffff;
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`0xffff`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 9;
'Project [unresolvedalias((0 + '0xffff), None)]
+- OneRowRelation$ (state=,code=0)
```

How do we express a hex literal in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, you can't do it in Spark SQL.

You can discover it just by looking at the [ANTLR grammar file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c42d208e197ff061cc5f49c75568c047d8d1126c/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4). There, the `number` rule defined via `DIGIT` lexer rule which looks like this:

```
number
  : MINUS? DECIMAL_VALUE            #decimalLiteral
  | MINUS? INTEGER_VALUE            #integerLiteral
  | MINUS? BIGINT_LITERAL           #bigIntLiteral
  | MINUS? SMALLINT_LITERAL         #smallIntLiteral
  | MINUS? TINYINT_LITERAL          #tinyIntLiteral
  | MINUS? DOUBLE_LITERAL           #doubleLiteral
  | MINUS? BIGDECIMAL_LITERAL       #bigDecimalLiteral
  ;

...

INTEGER_VALUE
  : DIGIT+
  ;

...

fragment DIGIT
  : [0-9]
  ;
```

It does not include any hexadecimal characters, so you can't use them.